# How does one prove differentiability?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

If I have a piecewise function, must I prove it is continous to show it is differentiable at a point? Or is it if I am able to apply the derivative rules to the function, it must be continous and therefore differentiable?

For Example:Is $f\left(x\right)$ is differentiable at 2? $$
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            4x^2+1 & \quad x > 2 \\
            17 & \quad x = 2 \\
            16x-15 & \quad x < 2
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$
Do I have to show $\lim \:_{x\to \:\:2}\:f\left(x\right)=f\left(2\right)$? Or can I assume that is true if $\frac{d}{dx+2}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)=\frac{d}{dx-2}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)$? I guess what I am really asking what is the criteria for a piece wise function to be differentiable at a point?

$$
f'(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            8x & \quad x > 2 \\
            0 & \quad x = 2 \\
            16 & \quad x < 2
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Is showing $f'_+\left(2\right)=f'_-\left(2\right)=16$ enough to say this function is differentiable? Also does it matter that $f'\left(2\right)=0$ and not $16$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove that a function is differentiable at a point $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we must prove that the limit
$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$$
exists. As an example let us study the differentiability of your function at $x = 2$ we have
$$ \frac{f(2 + h) - f(2)}{2} = \frac{f(2 + h) - 17}{h}$$
Now if $h > 0$ we have the right-side limit
$$ \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{4(2 + h)^2 + 1 - 17}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{16 + 16h + 4h^2 + 1 - 17}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{16h + 4h^2}{h} = 16$$
if $h < 0$ we have the left-side limit
$$ \lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{16(2 + h) - 15 - 17}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{32 + 16h - 15 - 17}{h} = 16$$
So the left and right sided limits agree, and the limit exists. We may conclude that $f$ is differentiable at $x = 2$. Can you handle the other point?

*An additional note on your answer*
Consider carefully whether your derivative "function" makes sense. You have implicitly assumed that $f'(2) = 0$ without proof! Note that in your version of the derivative function if $f(x) = a \in \mathbb{R}$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then $f'(x) = 0$. Consider the function defined by
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}2x, \ x > \frac{1}{2} \\ 1, \ x = \frac{1}{2} \\ 2x, \ x < \frac{1}{2} \end{cases}$$
This is a roundabout way to define $f(x) = 2x$. Using your formulation we would have
$$ f'(x) = \begin{cases}2, \ x > \frac{1}{2} \\ 0, \ x = \frac{1}{2} \\ 2, \ x < \frac{1}{2} \end{cases}$$
which is clearly absurd!

Comment: 17 is a constant. So the derivative of a constant is 0 because their is no slope. A proof would be $\lim _{h\to \:0}\left(\frac{17-17}{h}\right)=\lim \:_{h\to \:\:0}\left(\frac{0}{h}\right)=0$

Comment: Open your textbook and read the definition of the limit. Pay close attention to the fact that when defining the derivative there is a term of the form $f(x + h)$. For $h > 0$ this implies that $f(x + h) \not = f(x)$. So we do not have 17 - 17, but rather we must consider the values on the "left" and the "right".

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I am sorry if I did something really foolish. I am new at Calculus, so i am still learning some of the rules.

Comment: Of course not! You didn't do anything foolish. I am sorry if my tone implied this. There are always nuances in definitions that require special attention. Noone is assumed to be able to grasp them immediately without some tinkering.

Comment: I am a bit confused on how you got $4$ for the right side derivative

Comment: Oh you didn't distribute the $4$ in $4\left(2+h\right)^2$ correctly.

Comment: It is suppose to be $\lim _{h\to \:0+}\left(\frac{4\left(2+h\right)^2+1-17}{h}\right)=\lim \:_{h\to \:\:0+}\left(\frac{4\left(2^2+2\cdot 2h+h^2\right)-16}{h}\right)=\lim \:\:_{h\to \:\:\:0+}\left(\frac{4\cdot 2^2+4\cdot 2\cdot \:2h+4\cdot h^2-16}{h}\right)=\lim \:\:\:_{h\to \:\:\:\:0+}\left(\frac{16+16h+4\cdot \:h^2-16}{h}\right)=\lim \:\:\:\:_{h\to \:\:\:\:\:0+}\left(\frac{h\left(16+4h^2\right)}{h}\right)=16$

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct! Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

A function $f$ is said to be **continuous** at a point $a$ if
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) = f(a)
\end{equation*}

A function $f$ is said to be **differentiable** at a point $a$ if
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a} \qquad \text{exists}
\end{equation*}

So **differentiable** implies **continuous** (prove it as an exercise if you want; so you need to verify that

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow 2} \frac{f(x)  f(2)}{x-2}
\end{equation*}
exists, and you need to analyze the two possible ways that $x$ can tend to $2$ (left or right).

Comment: You mean $\lim _{x\to 2}\left(\frac{f\left(x\right)-f\left(2\right)}{x-2}\right)$, right? So I can just say since $\lim _{x\to 2+}\left(\frac{f\left(x\right)-f\left(2\right)}{x-2}\right)=16$ and $\lim _{x\to 2-}\left(\frac{f\left(x\right)-f\left(2\right)}{x-2}\right)=16$ then $f\left(x\right)$ is differentiable.